# ActivityCompat.requestPermissions

Tags: android

When my `Activity` calls `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions`, the UI dialog box does not appear.

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(HomeActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
```

I have this screen on the phone:

[image: Setup program stopped windows]

I do not know how to do, I try with:

```
requestPermissions( new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
```

I have the same result, if I put the line in comment and I have not the window that appears but I do not have the result (UI dialog box)

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: The application does not crash, I just have the message, after the application works properly (juste i dont have the UI for the Permissions) .

Comment: That message would indicate that your app crashed, if I am translating the message properly. I suggest that you double-check LogCat.

Comment: I have nothing in the logcat only information and verbose